# Usage of Next state and Clock Divider?

Tags: vhdl, clock, state-machines

I have a clock divider and state machine like this:

```
signal clk_200Hz : std_logic := '0';
signal counter : unsigned(19 downto 0) := x"00000";
begin

clkdiv : process (clk_100Mhz)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_100Mhz) then
        if counter = x"00000" then
            counter <= X"3D090"
            clk_200Hz <= not clk_200Hz;
        else
            counter <= counter - 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process clkdiv;
```

States:

```
 type SM_STATES is (state_column_1, scan_col_1, state_column_2, scan_col_2,
                          state_column_3, scan_col_3);
 signal my_state     : SM_STATES                   := state_column_1;
 -- By next state I mean something like this :
 -- signal my_state, my_next_state     : SM_STATES                   := state_column_1;
```

Below is the state machine:

```
scanner_sm : process (clk)
begin  -- process key_scanner
  if clk'event and clk = '1' then

  if clk_200Hz = '1' then -- clock divider finished counting down 

    -- reset scan_complete
    scan_complete <= '0';

case my_state is

  when state_column_1 =>
    scanned_val  <= (others => '0');
    original_col   <= "110";
    my_state <= scan_col_1;

  when scan_col_1 =>
    case bcd_val is
      when "1110" => 
      out_flag <= '1';
      scanned_val <= "1100100";  -- 1 wrong
      when "1101" => 
      out_flag <= '1';
      scanned_val <= "1100010";  -- 2 wrong
      when others => 
      out_flag <= '0';
      scanned_val <= "0010000";
    end case;
    my_state <= state_column_2;

  when state_column_2 =>
    original_col   <= "011";
    my_state <= scan_col_2;

  when scan_col_2 =>
    case bcd_val is
      when "1110" => 
    out_flag <= '1';
    scanned_val <= "1011011";  -- 5 wrong
      when "1101" => 
    out_flag <= '1';
    scanned_val <= "1011111";  -- 6 wrong
      when others =>
      out_flag <= '0';
      scanned_val <= "0000000";
    end case;
    my_state <= state_column_3;

  when state_column_3 =>
    original_col   <= "101";
    my_state <= scan_col_3;

  when scan_col_3 => -- Reading S1 // The only working state
    case bcd_val is
      when "1110" =>
    out_flag <= '1'; 
    scanned_val <= "1100000";  -- 9/ 1
      when "1101" => 
    out_flag <= '1';
    scanned_val <= "0111110";  -- X/ 2
      when others =>
     out_flag <= '0';
     scanned_val <= "0000000";
    end case;
    my_state <= state_column_1; -- 
    scan_complete <= '1'; -- 

  when others => scanned_val <= "0000000";
end case;

      end if;
  end if;
end process scanner_sm;
```

Question 1:
I don't have next state and everything works fine, do I need it? What is it good for? If everything is working without it, why would people need it? By next state I mean a second states type which contains the same states, starts with my_state, end of each state, state is switched to my_next_state and after each rising clock `my_state <= my_next_state`. Is this mealy or moore? According to me mealy. How many processes are involved in this and what are they?

Question 2: 
State machine is activated only if `clk_200Hz` is "1" I have 6 states, a full scan takes for me 1200 Hz or 200 Hz? My question is am I going to each state every 200 Hz or in 200Hz the whole 6 states are being scanned? If someone can elaborate this Clock events for the state machine, I would be glad!

Question 3:
How can I control the duration of `out_flag` I would like to make it lets say 70 ms, I would like increase its duration or maybe decrease, how can I do this? Default value of `out_flag` is zero.

Thanks a lot for reading!

Comment: Your code is not complete. What does this code do?  What do you mean by saying that you don't have a next state?!! In each state of your state diagram, you are assigning value to your `my_state`, which is your next state. Or you meant to say that you don't have a state named `next_state`?

Comment: Need more explanation on 'duration of `out_flag`' because its don't see its value changing.

Comment: @nidhin I want to send this `out_flag` to the processor, and the duration of out_flag and the interrupt job done should be the same. That is why I need to set to a fixed time. Default value is "0" and on `others` also set to "0". My code was incomplete, added more, sorry!

Comment: @nidhin Updated my question for Next state part as well.

Comment: What I understood is that you have to send `out_flag` to a processor every 70ms. For that, write a separate process which assigns the value every 70ms.

Comment: @nidhin Not every 70ms only and only when conditions matches then for 70ms. I'm new to VHDL, if I could write it alone I wouldn't ask the question.

Comment: pls see the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

1. You already define a next state in your clocked process.  If you had a non-clocked (combinational) next state process then you would explicitly define a `next_state` signal and route it to a clocked process defined somewhere else.
2. If your enable `clk_200hz` pulses every 200Hz and your state machine has 6 states it will take 6 enable pulses to cycle through your entire state machine.  So 1200Hz I guess, but that's kind of an unusual way to think about it.
3. The simplest thing to do would be to create a separate wait state after every state that sets `out_flag` and have the new wait state wait for 70ms before going to the next state.

**Edited:**

For 3 - Add something like this after each of your states

```
when example_wait1 =>
    if (count = 70) then -- adjust count to 70ms based off your clock speed
        count    <= (others => '0');
        my_state <= next_state;
    else
        count    <= count + 1;
        my_state <= example_wait1;
    end if;
...
when example_wait2 =>
    if (count = 70) then -- adjust count to 70ms based off your clock speed
        count    <= (others => '0');
        my_state <= next_state;
    else
        count    <= count + 1;
        my_state <= example_wait2;
    end if;
...
```

Comment: How do I implement this wait state?

Answer (score 0):

1.There is no keyword in VHDL named `next_state`. If you change from one state to other on any signal, then you have a present and next state. The machine you considered here is Mealy since its output (`out_flag`) depends on input (`scanned_val`) and present state.

2.This depends on the frequency of `clk`. The process `scanner_sm` is called every time when `clk` is changed. And it goes to your case statement if `clk_200Hz` is high (level triggered). I assume that your `clk_200Hz` has a frequency of 200Hz.

- If frequency of `clk` >> frequency of `clk_200Hz`, then it takes less than 0.5ms(time period of 200Hz signal) to scan your 6 states.
- If If frequency of `clk` << frequency of `clk_200Hz`, then it depends on the time period of `clk` which would be greater than 0.5ms.

3.I think you wanted to assign the value of `out_flag` to some processor pin. For that write a process like the one shown below and add it after your `clkdiv` process.

```
proc1:process(processor_pin)
begin
wait for 70 ms;
processor_pin <= out_flag;
end process proc1
```

Comment: is this going to wait for 70ms and then assign the flag or assign it for the duration of 70ms?

Comment: This assigns it for a duration of 70ms. This process copies the value of `out_flag` to `processor_pin` every 70ms. The value of `processor_pin` can change only  at multiples of 70ms where as `out_flag` can changed from other process during this period.